# regex not last one

Tags: regex

Here's some data

```
'132160,2011-05-25 09:50:21,
'121644,2011-02-26 05:14:51,
'119116,2011-01-10 21:43:16,
'113875,2010-11-20 22:09:57,
```

I'm in sublime text editor. I want to use find replace to replace the comma in the middle of each row with ['], (so closing the opening ' )

Using regex find replace if I type: `[,]$`

This highlights the last comma in each row. I want to inverse of this.

I tried `,[^$]` but that just selected all commas.

How do I select the not last comma?

I know I could use `\d,\d` but I wnat to know how to do using the not end with dollar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
,(?!$)
```

Comment: Or, if necessary, `,(?!(\r\n|\n))` ;-) Off topic, I presume your profile pic is in reference to the Game of Life?

Comment: @SpencerDoak yup, it's one of the smallest possible patterns that demonstrate infinite growth (http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Infinite_growth :)

Comment: @Blorgbeard, ahh very cool. I just went with a glider :P Anyway, didn't mean to make this go off-topic, but I just curios. Good answer, btw.